# How do I compress a file into .xip format?

Tags: xcode, zip, compression

I wanted to compress the Xcode.app I downloaded from the app store into .xip format. Is it the same as compressing it to .zip and renaming?

Comment: The usual way t compress and package an app is to create a compressed disk image and copy the app to it - why do you need a.xip file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, .xip files have nothing to do with .zip files - it's not the same format at all. .xip files are really a type of xar archive.

If you want to compress your own .xip file, you can do that with the `xip` command in macOS:

```
xip file1 file2 file3 archive.xip
```

However you cannot compress Xcode.app to a .xip file and send that to others and expect them to be able to just unpack it by double-clicking. The file will be verified to see if the .xip is signed by Apple - if it is not, it will not be automatically unpacked.

Comment: Wow, very helpful answer, thank you!